# vim: how to replace "empty_space\n" into "\n"

Tags: vim, newline

I have a text file ending with "empty_space\n"

```
...{empty_space}
...{empty_space}
```

I want to remove the empty spaces at the end so to say.

```
...
...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`:%s/\v\s+$//`

- `:` Ex command
- `%` on all lines
- `s` substitute
- `/` start pattern
- `\v` very magic mode (makes `\s` available)
- `\s` any whitespace
- `+` one or more characters
- `$` end of line
- `/` end of pattern
- empty replacement
- `/` end of replacement

Comment: I want to replace only the very last empty space before the new line. Spaces coming before that should remain.

Comment: Oh, then simply do `:%s/ $//`.

Answer (score 1):

`:%s/ $//` should work.

Let me break it down

`:`<- command mode

`%s` find each occcurence

then the regular expressions to be matched and replaced by.

Comment: `g` is global mode, which isn't needed here because there's only one substitution per line. There's no confirmation by default (you enable it with `c`).